# REST Web Service with Netty

Tags: resteasy, netty

Is there any recommended way to implement REST Web Service with Netty?
I am a RESTEasy user, is there a way to use Netty and RESTEasy together?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like since version 2.3.4 of RESTEasy it supports an embedded Netty container: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Embedded_Container.html#d0e2690

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way to use RESTEasy with Netty. I used restexpress [1] in the past.

[1] https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress

Comment: I tried RestExpress. It is a simple and easy-to-learn framework. Thanks.

Comment: RestExpress doesn't seem mature enough for my application, where security is critical. Is there any other alternative? (for a JavaSE application, and if possible with a support for Maven).

Answer (score 0):

Resteasy + Spring + Netty sample I used : https://github.com/leiguorui/netty-resteasy-spring